# JNDI .bindings file gets corrupted with \u0000

Tags: jndi, corrupt

Has anyone had any experience with a JNDI .bindings file becoming corrupted under WebSphere with extraneous sequences of \u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000 characters?
This happens infrequently, and when it does, we remove the .bindings file and it is regenerated correctly without the \u0000 characters.
We don't know the root cause though.

Answer (score 0):

We've also had a similar problem.  We're using DB2 V9.5 Fix Pak 3b with HADR and automatic client reroute.   We consistently get the corruption in the .bindings file when we do a HADR takeover and I'm not sure if it is db2 or automatic client reroute that is writing the \u0000 into that file. We have the problem with 2 db2 installations but don't have the problem with the other 4.  Still trying to figure out where the root cause is.